# Как разбить массив char на числа через разделитель?

Tags: c++, массивы, char

Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос: из текстового файла я вытягиваю строчку в массив char, которая выглядит примерно как {5_12_-3_89_1_-1#}, можно как-то его разделить на отдельные числа, разделенные  знаком "_"? чтобы первый элемент массива был 5, второй - 12, третий - -3, и т.д.?

Answer (score 6):

Наиболее корректный (C++-ный) вариант исполнения через `std::getline()`:

```
const char* line = "5_12_-3_89_1_-1#";
std::string num;
std::stringstream nums(line);
while (std::getline(nums, num, '_'))
{
//work with num
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на чистом С (работает ТОЛЬКО для строки типа `/^\d+(_\d+)*\D*$/`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int explode_string(char* src, char separator, int **dest) {
    int parts_number = 1;
    char *s;
    for (s = src; *s; ++s)
        if (*s == separator) ++parts_number;
    *dest = (int*) malloc(parts_number * sizeof(int));
    char *pStart = src, *pEnd;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < parts_number; ++i) {
        (*dest)[i] = strtol(pStart, &pEnd, 10);
        pStart = pEnd + 1;
    }
    return parts_number;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *list;
    int n = explode_string("123_456", '_', &list);
    printf("Number of numbers = %d\n", n);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
        printf("\t%d\n", list[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для вытаскивания в цикле из строки слов, разделенных заданными символами Вы можете использовать вот такую функцию

```
#include <string.h>

/*
 before call: *p -- ptr to start search WORD in delimiters
 after call:  *p -- ptr to next char after word (and *p - word == WORD length)
 returns ptr to WORD or 0
 */
char *
strtos (char **p, const char *delim)
{
  char *word = 0;

  if (*((*p) += strspn(*p, delim))) {
    word = *p;
    (*p) += strcspn(*p, delim);
  }

  return word;
}
```

Тогда простенькая программа, просто печатающая их может выглядеть так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () 
{
  char buf[1024];
  extern char *strtos(char **, const char *);

  while (fgets(buf, 1024, stdin)) {
    char *p, *e, *ep = buf;
    while (p = strtos(&ep, "_\n#")) { // смотрите, как похоже на чтение строк из файла!!!
      // тут остается взять число, на которое указывает p 
      // и поместить его в массив
      char w[ep - p + 1];
      strncpy(w, p, ep - p); w[ep - p] = 0;
      printf("[%s]: %ld  ", w, strtol(w, &e, 10));
      if (*e)
        puts("invalid");
    }
    puts("");
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Здесь в качестве разделителей кроме `_` указаны еще и  завершающие символы  `#` с `\n`, который будет прочитан в `buf` для каждой строки.

Вам остается вместо `printf()` поместить число в массив.
Обратите внимание, что для размещения числа в массиве (и анализе его правильности) с помощью `strtol()` впомогательный массив `w[]`, в который копируется очередное слово не нужен. Но анализ правильности ввода несколько изменится, в Вашем случае символ на котрый указывает `e` д.б. `_` или `#` (конец ввода).